# mobile keyboard change my layout (i used vmax in css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to build some websites, but I have a problem when I switch to mobile view. All the CSS works fine, but whenever I try to type something in a textarea, a keyboard appears and its effects are a little bit different in css.
I used vmax in all sizing variables.

My website's temporary link : https://tourmaline-florentine-7201fe.netlify.app/
[enter link description here](https://tourmaline-florentine-7201fe.netlify.app/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.App {
    background-color: #ff738b;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.App > h1 {
    padding: 1vmax;
    font: 400 3vmax cursive;
    color: #583069;
}

.input_div {
    height: 20vmax;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}
.input_div > textarea {
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 12vmax;
    width: 55vmax;
    overflow: wrap;
    margin: 1vmax;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1vmax;
    background-color: #ffb58e;
    outline: none;
}

.input_div > button {
    width: 15vmax;
    height: 3.5vmax;
    border: none;
    background-color: #583069;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.input_div > button:hover {
    background-color: #913673;
}

.Time_input_div {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.Time_input_div > h1 {
    font: 400 2vmax cursive;
    color: #583069;
}
.Time_input_div > h2 {
    font: 400 2vmax cursive;
    color: #583069;
}

.timePopUp_social > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1vmax;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.timePopUp_social > a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.main_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 4vmax;
}

.container {
    min-height: 15vmax;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffb58e;
    margin: 2vmax;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container > button {
    width: 10vmax;
    height: 2.5vmax;
    border: none;
    background-color: #583069;
    color: white;
    margin: 1vmax;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.container > button:hover {
    background-color: #913673;
}

.time {
    font-size: 1vmax;
    color: #583069;
    margin: 1vmax;
}

.date {
    font-size: 1vmax;
    color: #583069;
    margin: 1vmax;
}
.text {
    font-size: 1.5vmax;
    color: #583069;
    margin: 1vmax;
    padding-left: 2vmax;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2vmax;
    color: #132615;
    margin: 1vmax;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .App > h1 {
        padding: 2vmax;
        font: 400 4vmax cursive;
        color: #583069;
    }
    .input_div > textarea {
        height: 16vmax;
        width: 85%;
    }
    .input_div > button {
        font: 300 2.2vmax "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }
    .main_container {
        margin-top: 2vmax;
    }

    .container {
        min-height: 20vmax;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 2vmax;
    }

    .container > button {
        width: 12vmax;
        height: 3.5vmax;
        margin: 1.4vmax;
        font: 300 2vmax "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }
    .time {
        font-size: 1.8vmax;
        margin: 1vmax;
    }

    .date {
        font-size: 1.8vmax;
        margin: 1vmax;
    }
    .text {
        font-size: 2.2vmax;
        margin: 1vmax;
        padding-left: 3vmax;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 3vmax;
        margin: 1.5vmax;
    }
    .Time_input_div > h1 {
        font: 400 3vmax cursive;
        color: #583069;
    }
    .Time_input_div > h2 {
        font: 400 3vmax cursive;
        color: #583069;
    }
}
```